# How can I \typeout a percent sign?

Tags: expansion, percent-sign

I want to `\typeout` a message containing a percent sign. I know that if I want to `\typeout` a macro followed by a space, as in:

```
The name Name is unknown.
```

I have to use `\space`, not `\␣`, because `\space` is expandable and `\␣` is not. So the message would be coded like this:

```
\typeout{The name \name\space is unknown.}
```

What if I want to put a percent sign in a message? I tried `\%`, but it remains as `\%` in the final message. So obviously, like `\␣` it is not expandable. I also tried `\percent` (undefined) and `\textpercent` (also seemingly not expandable).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\@percentchar` in a place where `@` is a letter

(or `\csname @percentchar\endcsname` otherwise)

Comment: I've never known for sure… the only reason `\%` is not expandable is because TeX has to play a little with the font because `%` is not in the “correct slot”? In an ideal XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with OpenType fonts it could be expandable, right?

Comment: @Manuel well not really `\%` isn't defined to be an encoding specific command, it's simply defined by `\chardef` to be character 37, it could be defined as `\@percentchar`, it just isn't. (same for `\&` and `\#`)

Comment: Ahm, I think that was the case with `\textbackslash` and `\textquoteleft ` and `\textquoteright` (correct me if I'm mistaken), so I thought it was the case with `\%`.

Comment: @Manuel yes those are encoding specific (and added in latex2e) `\%` just comes from plain and has always been there.